# Econometrics especially with regard to OLS estimators!

Tags: econometrics, mathematical-economics, statistics

I am solving a problem below and also having a hard time. Could you give me a help me with it?

Which of the following can cause OLS estimators to be biased? Which of the following do not cause the usual OLS t statistics to be invlaid (that is, to have t distributions under H0)?

- Omitting an important independent variable
- Multicollinearity
- Heteroskedasticity
- Including irrelevant variable
- The error term non-normally distributed

Comment: Hi @berrystraw. I think you should write out in non-technical terms what biased/unbiased means in the context of an OLS estimator. This may help you identify sources of bias. One such source may be the omitted variable bias noted above.

Comment: Cross-posting tends to be discouraged: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/616817/247274

Comment: Hi, this looks like homework/self-study question, note we have a rule where homework questions have to first show attempt at trying to figure out solution. Please tell us which issues from the list you think cause OLS to be biased and why and then we can correct you